# Is there any open source Object to XML serializer in Java that uses writeObject method

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Is there any open source Object to XML serializer in Java that uses writeObject method on the object to serialize similar to NSXMLOutputStream in WebObjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but I would suggest you look at [JAXB](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/), one great Java standard for XML serialization.

Most of the serialization can be defined using **annotations**, but you can provide your own serialization as well using so-called **adapters**.

You can then marshall/unmarshall from/to XML as you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512337/custom-serialization-in-jaxb/527683#527683) for an example.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://x-stream.github.io/ though I don't know if it use those methods on the class Object.

What do you want to use those methods?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. XStream worked wonderfully for me!

Comment: xstream succeeded where XMLEncoder failed with 'discarding ...'

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [XMLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)/[XMLDecoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) classes, which behave like obejct serialization in XML.

These classes are part of the JDK since its 1.4 version.

Comment: Voting for that one since it's a core API; I do however agree that there are numerous 3rd party implementations which also do quite well.